# DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message - How can I check if a message is deleted before attempting to delete it

Tags: discord, discord.js

In a hypothetical situation like below, the bot can send an embed then delete the message in 3 seconds.

```js
message.reply({ embeds: [embed] })
.then((msg) => {
setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 3000)
})
```

When a user deletes the message before the bot, the bot crashes and I get this error:

```cmd
C:\Users\\Documents\GitHub\omex\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\\Documents\GitHub\\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\\Documents\GitHub\\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async MessageManager.delete (C:\Users\\Documents\GitHub\\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\MessageManager.js:205:5)
    at async Message.delete (C:\Users\\Documents\GitHub\\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Message.js:709:5) {
  method: 'delete',
  path: '/channels/877943546932494377/messages/888575942379847681',
  code: 10008,
  httpStatus: 404,
  requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
}
```

So is there a way to detect if a message is deleted before attempting to delete it?

Answer (score 1):

".deleted" returns a boolean with which you could check.
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=deleted

Or if you don't care about the error, you could also just use ".catch" after ".then". Tho, it's probably better to avoid the error in the first place with the above.

Comment: I get the same Unknown Message error even after adding `if (!msg.deleted) {setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 3000)}`

Answer (score 1):

Building off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69230623/12464931) by [TayDex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16202753/taydex) you should check `Message#deleted` *after* the timeout has ended. The reason being is that once the timer starts, it's possible that the message gets deleted within the 3 seconds it's counting down.

**Additionally** you can add a `catch()` callback to `Message#delete()` for error handling and preventing crashes.

```js
message.reply({ embeds: [embed] })
.then(msg => {
   setTimeout(() => {
      if (!msg.deleted) {
         msg.delete()
         .catch(err => {
            console.log('An error occurred but the bot is still running')
            console.error(err)
         })
      }
   }, 3000)
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't I not be getting an error message if the `if` statement works. I still get the console logs but I'm wondering why it's even running all that when the message is deleted.

Comment: I include the error handling for exemplifying handling promise errors as well as just having a final net to prevent crashes. It's also possible the requests fails due to other reasons unrelated to deleting the message. The catch callback *shouldn't* be firing if the promise was resolved. What does `err` return?

Comment: The error returns `DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message` which is the same as the error in the original question.